# Reflash 1st Gen Kindle Fire Bootloader?

Tags: boot-loop, bootloader, amazon-kindle-fire

I rooted my Kindle Fire and flashed [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2), [FireFireFire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1369405), and [AOKP](http://aokp.co/), and it's been working fine for a while. Recently, however, there have been strange problems with the bootloader. It has gotten to the point where the bootloader requires the user to select how to boot, then crashes and starts up again. How can I reflash FireFireFire to my device? Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is FFF? From the context, it's either a custom recovery like [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2), or a custom ROM like [AOKP](https://github.com/aokp) (as the [Fedetation of Fly Fishers](http://www.fedflyfishers.org/) makes no sense here, nor does [this FFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuck_for_Forest) (ouch!)). Mind to provide an explanation? ;)

Comment: FFF is a custom bootloader, short for FireFireFire. I need to reflash it in order to fix the issues that have been cropping up with booting the device.

Comment: Would it not work if you flashed it using the same method used before?